# A woman has her purse snatched by two teenagers...

Tags: statistics

A woman has her purse snatched by two teenagers. She is subsequently shown a police lineup consisting of five suspects, including two perpetrators. What is the sample space associated with the experiment " woman picks two suspects out of lineup"? Which outcomes are in the event $A$: she makes at least one incorrect identification?

So far I have: (With $p$ (perpetrator) and $i$ (innocent) )

$S = \{ (p_1,i_1), (p_1, i_3,), (p_2,i_1), (p_2,i_2,), (p_2,i_3), (p_1,p_2), (i_1,i_2), (i_1,i_3), (i_2,i_3)\}$

But I am unsure how to do event $A$: she makes at least one incorrect identification?

Would it be:

$S = \{ (p_1,i_1), (p_1, i_3), (p_2,i_1), (p_2,i_2), (p_2,i_3), (i_1,i_2), (i_1,i_3), (i_2,i_3)\}$?

Comment: What are terms like $ p_1$ and $ i_1 $?

Comment: They stand for perpetrator and innocent

Comment: This problem is from a school in a gentrifying neighborhood? ;/

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Highly recommended.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should mention what notations you have used.

So I define:

$p_i=$the $i^{th}$ perpetrator, $i=1,2$

and

$i_j=$the $j^{th}$ innocent person, $j=1,2,3$

So the sample space associated with the experiment 1 is

$(p_1,i_1),(p_1,i_2),(p_1,i_3),(p_2,i_1),(p_2,i_2),(p_2,i_3),(i_1,i_2),(i_1,i_3),(i_2,i_3),(p_1,p_2)$

AND

the outcomes associated with the event A is

$(p_1,i_1),(p_1,i_2),(p_1,i_3),(p_2,i_1),(p_2,i_2),(p_2,i_3),(i_1,i_2),(i_1,i_3),(i_2,i_3)$

Hope the reasoning is understandable.

Answer (score 0):

The sample space is, by basic combinations, $\dbinom{5}{2} = 10$, because the woman chooses two from five. The space $A$ is the complement of the space in which the woman gets both the perpetrators. There is only $1$ way the woman gets both, so $A$ has size $10 - 1 = 9$. I am not sure exactly what you mean by the items $p_1, ...$ and $i_1, ...$, but if we say that $w_p$ is the event of the woman choosing perpetrator $p$ and $a_p$ is the event that $p$ is actually the perp, $A = {(w_1, w_2, a_1, a_3), (w_1, w_2, a_1, a_4), ..., (w_4, w_5, a_3, a_5)}$. I am not entirely sure why you want to explicitly define this space, though.